# ImageView in Scrollview appears upside down

Tags: ios, imageview, scrollview

I have created a scrolling/zooming image view by placing a UIImageView within a UIScrollView.  The behavior is exactly as I desire and would expect, however the image is appearing upside down within the scrollview.

Here is how I am handling the initialization, zooming, and scrolling:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1f;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 0.5f;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];

}

 - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageView;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of it in the simulator.

[image]

The imageview/scrollview are both created and set in interface builder.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been able to confirm that the imageView istself is upside down, and not just the image?

if that is not the case, you could just force it with something like [imageView setFrame:someFrame]

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not sure what I would have done to make the imageview itself upside down from Interface Builder.  I did just now try doing imageView.frame = CGRectMake() and I still encounter the same issue.

Comment: Interestingly enough, though, setting the frame to something smaller has caused it to appear the correct orientation.  It seems that IB/iOS did not like me having a 3264x2448 image view.

Comment: That is the strangest thing I've heard in a long time... I have no idea what would cause that sorry.

Comment: Accepting answer because what fixed the problem is in my second comment